# Javascript based XMPP chatclient using strophe js - Examples and tutorials?

Tags: javascript, xmpp

I want to make a simple javascript-based XMPP client. I stumbled upon 'strophe js', which should make my life easier when it comes to XMPP but I find the documentation a bit.. uncomplete. It has an example on how to connect/disconnect but that's pretty much it.

I need to get a list of contacts, send and receive messages... how do I do this?

Actually: where can I find a tutorial or an example on how to do this? (no need to write a full tut here :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can find your requirement related to chat using **stropher js for XMPP protocol** on this below working github code.

https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp

**Look on chap :06  demo (GAB Tut)**.

It will satisfy all your requirement related to

- one to one chat.
- Roster list (Friend list),
- Send friend request,
- In coming request approval.
- Start one to one chat etc...

  and all important demo also included

Let me know you have any query in this demo. :) :)

Comment: Just took a look at it, I think this is what I need to get started. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check out this project : https://conversejs.org/

This is a really good implementation of using Strophe.js and also uses Backbone Js to to ease it up. Hope it helps.